# Full text search find a part of word

Tags: sql-server

I see several of questions about this topic , but I didn't find
an answer:

Can full-text search can search a part of the word  and not from the begin of the word or the end 
for example

```
last name= 'rexxxtt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Supported Forms of Query Terms (Full-Text Search)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879300.aspx) article on MSDN. The short answer is no. You can't use `*` as first character. You can use only prefix searches, not FullText Search `LIKE` or try to cheat using `REVERSE` tricks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
Where [last name] like 're___tt'
```

re(3 underscore characters)tt. It means your lastname begins with 're' and ends with 'tt'. There should be 3 characters in between 're' and 'tt'

Comment: can i do it with full text search? a

Comment: Your requirement is lastname begins with 're' and ends with 'tt' and there should be 3 characters in between 're' and 'tt'. Isn't it? If yes, then you can do simple like operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search a substring use:

```
last name like '%'+'rexxxtt'+'%'
```